# C program crashes on Scanf use, after int input

Tags: c, scanf

probably another dumb error but I really can't wrap my head around this.
I'm writing a basic polynomials class, and my program suddenly crashes upon input of a couple of ints.. I tried searching for a solution but I couldn't find one :/

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Homework.h"
#include "Fraction.h"

int main()
{
  //Input from user
  int degree, i;
  printf("Insert the degree of the polynomomial: \n");
  scanf("%d", &degree);

  //Get the coefficcients
  struct fraction *bucket = malloc((sizeof(struct fraction))*(degree + 1));
  int num;
  unsigned int den;
  for(i = 0; i < degree + 1; i++)
  {
    num = 0;
    den = 1;
    printf("Insert the coefficcient of degree %d, first num and afterwards 
the den \n", i);
    printf("Numerator:\n");
    if(scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
      printf("Input error\n");
    printf("Denominator:\n");
    if(scanf("%u", &den) != 1)
      printf("Input error\n");
    //struct fraction temp = {num, den};
    //memcpy(&bucket[0], &temp, sizeof(struct fraction));
  }

  //Check insertion
  printf("Test\n");
  //print_fraction(bucket[0]);
}
```

The program exits even before printing "Test", and to input I am using input number + enter key.

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Posted code looks okay, although there are issues in the commented-out lines storing into `bucket`.  Does it crash before or after prompting you for the degree?  Before or after entering the first coefficients, or the second, or what?

Comment: @SteveSummit So you think that this `struct fraction *bucket = malloc((sizeof(struct fraction))*(degree + 1));` looks fine?

Comment: It's fine, but you need to check the return value.

Comment: @SteveSummit And how can you check this based on OPs code ? `struct fraction *bucket = malloc((sizeof(struct fraction))*(degree + 1));`  =>>> `error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct fraction’` ... or you have more informations about `#include "Fraction.h"` ? which we do not.

Comment: Adding a return value seems to solve the problem, thanks! @SteveSummit

Comment: @Michi Sorry, when I answered your question, I mistakenly assumed it was Matteo asking.  But yes, I reaffirm that the `malloc` call looks fine.  (Although, yes, when I said that I made an educated guess about `struct fraction` and `Fraction.h`.)

Comment: @MatteoPagin I'm actually not sure what return value you mean, but if you're making progress, I'm glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

[Proof it compiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flfRH.png)

Your code seems to be working fine. 
The only changes i've made in order to compile it was to comment out the line where you are using malloc, and also brought your print statement on one line.

If you are using a newer version of Visual Studio then it will give you issues when using the scanf function. You either have to use scanf_s or disable the warning with this line at the top:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please explain us, how can you proof that a code works fine if you include some files which you do not have them?